# copy efs encrypted file to another computer using old pc password

Tags: windows-7, efs

I encrypted several drives on my old pc. The pc is sold but I kept the hard disk. Now I want to copy some very important files from the old hard disk to my laptop but I can only access the drive where windows7 was installed. All other drive says 'access denied'.  I can remember the old pc password and tried to boot my laptop from that old hdd. Booting from the old hdd fails with a blue screen. How can I access the drives?

Comment: It was EFS, right, and not BitLocker?

Comment: Yes efs. Not BitLocker.

Comment: If all files ("All other drive") are giving an Access Denied message, I would wonder if you need to start by Taking Ownership of the folders/files and then Giving your new account (at least) Read/Traversal rights on the folders/files.

Answer (score 1):

First up I would recommend you take an image of the old disk before doing anything further with it. There are plenty of imaging utilities out there so use your preferred tool of choice.

Your blue screens are most likely due to the hardware being completely different to that of your old machine so you will most likely need to 'repair' the installation that is on it. This would mean using a boot disk with the OS you were using on your old machine (plus any Service Packs you may have installed.)

With your old hard disk installed, boot with the Operating System boot CD/DVD and follow the prompts for repairing the installation. From there, you may be able to be in a position to recovery the encrypted drives.